# is it possible to fixed the python environment when error IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory occurs

Tags: python

Today when I using the YouTube-dl to download some videos in my Mac, shows error like this:

```
> youtube-dl -o "$HOME/Videos/%(title)s.%(ext)s" 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0YiWsAM0O8'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/youtube-dl", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('youtube-dl==2021.12.17', 'console_scripts', 'youtube-dl')())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 475, in main
    _real_main(argv)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 442, in _real_main
    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 422, in __init__
    self._setup_opener()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2395, in _setup_opener
    https_handler = make_HTTPS_handler(self.params, debuglevel=debuglevel)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 2297, in make_HTTPS_handler
    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 776, in create_default_context
    context.keylog_filename = keylogfile
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/John/apps/wireshark'
```

the log output is wired, I am sure the YouTube-dl command was correct. I think the python 3.10 maybe was misconfiguration, so I tried to reinstall the python 3.10 like this:

```
brew reinstall python@3.10
```

but still did not fixed this issue. is it possible to fixed this issue? It looks like the python environment issue because any of YouTube command will cause this issue:

```
> youtube-dl version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/youtube-dl", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('youtube-dl==2021.12.17', 'console_scripts', 'youtube-dl')())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 475, in main
    _real_main(argv)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 442, in _real_main
    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 422, in __init__
    self._setup_opener()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2395, in _setup_opener
    https_handler = make_HTTPS_handler(self.params, debuglevel=debuglevel)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/youtube-dl/2021.12.17/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 2297, in make_HTTPS_handler
    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 776, in create_default_context
    context.keylog_filename = keylogfile
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/John/apps/wireshark'
```

I also tried to upgrade the YouTube-dl:

```
> brew upgrade youtube-dl
fatal: not in a git directory
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services, skipping update!
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
Warning: youtube-dl 2021.12.17 already installed
```